# Spring Starter Projectの作成中にZipExceptionが発生する

Tags: spring-boot

【やりたいこと】
spring boot用のプロジェクトを新規作成する

【環境】
Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3RC3)
プラグイン: Spring Tool Suite(STS) for Eclipse 3.8.3 RELEASE, Gradle IDE Pack 3.8.x+1.0.x

【手順】
Eclipse: New→Spring Starter Projectを選択
Type: Gradle(STS)
Packaging: Jar
Java Version: 1.8
Language: Java
Nextを押下
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.2
JPA, PostgreSQL, Thymeleaf, Webを選択
Finishを押下

【エラー表示】
Problem Occurredというダイアログが表示されます。

> Import Getting Started Content has encountered a problem.
>   ZipException: error in opening zip file
>
> 詳細
>   ZipException: error in opening zip file
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

エラーメッセージによれば、zipファイルが開けなくてエラーになっているようです。
Gradeプラグインにzip関連のツールも入っているようなので、問題ないと思うのですが
メッセージで検索してみましたが、特にずばりの回答は見つかりませんでした。

設定の問題でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

ホームディレクトリの.gradleを削除してプロジェクトの作成を再実行したらうまく行きました。
うーん、gradleのこの辺の勝手にライブラリーをダウンロードしてきて場合によっては競合したり
今回のようにエラーになるの好きじゃないですね。